# Rotate iAd with orientation change (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, iad

I have a Universal app (iPhone/iPad) which has an iAd displayed at the bottom of the view.

I use the following code to position it on view load;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    bannerIsVisible = YES;
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    float origin_y;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
        origin_y = 360.0;
    else
        origin_y = self.view.frame.size.height;

    adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,origin_y, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
adView.delegate = self;

    if ( &ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != NULL ) {
        adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;

else  {
        adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers  = [NSSet  setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier  = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
    }

    [self.view  bringSubviewToFront:adView];
[webView  addSubview:adView];

    [super  viewDidLoad];
}
```

Now I want to support all 4 orienations i.e. the iAd should move to the bottom on all the 4 orienations

So my question is simply how do I update the following code to support the same;

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientationUIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return  YES;
}
```

Please note 2 things;
 1. I need the same code to work on both iPhone/iPad
 2. I am ready to update the fixed value of origin_y from 360.0 to whatever you can suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the autoResizingMask, like this :

```
[adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  
 |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    
 |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ];
```

Without the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`, this means that the object will keep the same margin from the bottom of the screen in every device orientation, so stay at the bottom in your case.

Comment: Thx a lot...Actually I have never heard of or used autoResizingMask....Could you please provide more details as to how I can integrate it in the code that I have...Also if I need to make any update to CGRectMake(0.0,origin_y, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height); adView.delegate = self;